# Jupyter: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'Export.csv', can't save a .csv file with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I'm trying to save a pandas dataframe to a .csv file using `df.to_csv("Export.csv", index=False)`. The `Export.csv` doesn't exist yet and is also not opened by another program. I'm always getting the error: `PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'Export.csv'`. I'm working on Windows 10 and the error never occured until now working in the same way. Does anyone know how to solve this problem and could help me please?

Full error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
PermissionError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-34-3f912ccf3ece> in <module>
----> 1 df.to_csv("Export.csv", index=False)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in to_csv(self, path_or_buf, sep, na_rep, float_format, columns, header, index, index_label, mode, encoding, compression, quoting, quotechar, line_terminator, chunksize, date_format, doublequote, escapechar, decimal, errors, storage_options)
   3385         )
   3386 
-> 3387         return DataFrameRenderer(formatter).to_csv(
   3388             path_or_buf,
   3389             line_terminator=line_terminator,

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\format.py in to_csv(self, path_or_buf, encoding, sep, columns, index_label, mode, compression, quoting, quotechar, line_terminator, chunksize, date_format, doublequote, escapechar, errors, storage_options)
   1081             formatter=self.fmt,
   1082         )
-> 1083         csv_formatter.save()
   1084 
   1085         if created_buffer:

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\csvs.py in save(self)
    226         """
    227         # apply compression and byte/text conversion
--> 228         with get_handle(
    229             self.filepath_or_buffer,
    230             self.mode,

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\common.py in get_handle(path_or_buf, mode, encoding, compression, memory_map, is_text, errors, storage_options)
    640                 errors = "replace"
    641             # Encoding
--> 642             handle = open(
    643                 handle,
    644                 ioargs.mode,

PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'Export.csv'
```

Answer (score 0):

This Exception generally comes when you have opened same csv or excel file. You can close any file if opened.